# What kinds of characteristics and outcomes are associated with low agreeableness and high honesty–humility?

Tags: personality

I've heard low agreeableness is correlated with low honesty–humility, under HEXACO's model. However, it seems plausible to me that one could have low agreeableness and high honesty–humility, like a brutally honest, rough-around-the-edges, but principled type. I've tried searching for studies regarding such people, but can't find any. What kind of things are associated with people of this combination?